# Postgres get element rank after calculation

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's hard to put it in words what I am trying to do. My knowledge in SQL too weak to use right terminology, so I will try to illustrate it as example.

Say, I have a big table consisting columns "value", "user" and "type"

```
value|user_id|type|

  100|      1|   1|
  200|      1|   1|
  100|      1|   2|
  722|      1|   3|
   48|      2|   1|
  724|      2|   2|
  175|      2|   3|
```

1) I calculate sum "value" for each "user_id" for each "type".

```
SELECT SUM("value"), "user_id", "type" from "table" group by "user_id", "type"
```

giving me

```
value|user_id|type|

  300|      1|   1|
  100|      1|   2|
  722|      1|   3|
   48|      2|   1|
  724|      2|   2|
  175|      2|   3|
```

2) I want to obtain rank of "user_id" for each "type" based on the "value".

For type 1, value for user 1 is greater than for user 2, so user 1 ranks as 1 and user 2 ranks 2.
For type 2, value for user 2 is greater...

In other words I want to produce table for user 1:

```
rank|type
   1|1
   2|2
   1|3
```

and for user 2:

```
rank|type
   2|1
   1|2
   2|3
```

I would really appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the result of an aggregate function for a window function. The window function will be processed after the `group by`:

```
SELECT sum(value), user_id, type, 
       rank() over (partition by type order by sum(value) desc) 
from the_table 
group by user_id, type
order by user_id, type;
```

Comment: Wow it works and so simple! Thank you!! Is there a way to select the data only for given user_id, say user_id=1?

Comment: @Winten . .  Use this as a CTE or subquery, and then select from it with a `WHERE` clause.